Questions Pertaining to Fundamental Mathematical Knowledge and Set Theory
In the category of modules over a ring $R$, we can define the direct sum of a set of modules. The direct sum of $\lbrace M_{i} \rbrace_{i\in I}$ is denoted by $$ \bigoplus_{i\in I} M_{i} \ .$$
My question is:
If $I$ is the empty set, then is $ \bigoplus_{i\in I} M_{i}$ defined as $0$(the zero module) or the empty set? In other words, is the direct sum of
the empty set of modules defined as $0$ or the empty set?
Similarly:
Is the direct product $\prod_{i\in I} M_{i}$ of the empty set of modules defined as $0$ or the empty set?
Is the sum $\sum_{i\in I} M_{i}$ of the empty set of modules defined as $0$ or the empty set, where $\lbrace M_{i} \rbrace_{i\in I}$ are submodules of $M$? In other words, when $I$ is the empty set and $\lbrace M_{i} \rbrace_{i\in I}$ are submodules of a module $M$, is the sum $\sum_{i\in I} M_{i}$ defined as $0$ or the empty set?
Is the intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I} M_{i}$ of the empty set of modules defined as $0$ or the empty set, where $\lbrace M_{i} \rbrace_{i\in I}$ are submodules of $M$? In other words, when $I$ is the empty set and $\lbrace M_{i} \rbrace_{i\in I}$ are submodules of a module $M$, is the intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I} M_{i}$ defined as $0$ or the empty set?
Is the union $\bigcup_{i\in I} M_{i}$ of the empty set of modules defined as $0$ or the empty set, where $\lbrace M_{i} \rbrace_{i\in I}$ are submodules of $M$? In other words, when $I$ is the empty set and $\lbrace M_{i} \rbrace_{i\in I}$ are submodules of a module $M$, is the union $\bigcup_{i\in I} M_{i}$ defined as $0$ or the empty set?

This adds to Fernando’s answer. Since you used the word category: the empty product is the terminal object of a category, and the empty coproduct is the initial object of a category.

In general, it's very hard to assign sense to an intersection $\bigcap_{i \in I} M_i$ of modules (as a module) unless the $M_i$ are assumed to be submodules of some given module. For example, if $M_1 = {0, 1}$ and $M_2 = {a, b}$ have no elements in common but both have assigned $\mathbb{Z}$-module structures, then their intersection cannot be a module at all because all modules have at least a zero element. (I see Josh Keneda posted a similar comment below Fernando's answer.)

@user43298 Thank you for your corrections. My question has changed to the following:
When $I$ is the empty set and $\lbrace M_{i} \rbrace_{i\in I}$ are submodules of a module $M$, is the intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I} M_{i}$ defined as $0$ or the empty set?

@LiangChen Neither, as Jair Taylor has said, except that his response should be changed from this "$U$" to $M$.

Thank you. I understand your point.

I would just like to point out the obvious fact that the empty set is not a module at all (a module encompasses in particular an Abelian group for addition, which must have a neutral (zero) element). So defining any kind of module as the empty set is not an option.

The direct sum should behave like a sum, in particular if we "sum" sets (take their coproduct), we should have $\bigoplus_{i\in I+J} M_{i}$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_{i} \oplus \bigoplus_{j\in J} M_{i}$. For this to hold, we must define $\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_{i}$ to be $0$. A similar analysis answers your other questions.
More precisely, if we define the sum of modules to be its categorical coproduct, then we must define $\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_{i}$ to be $0$. Similarly for the other cases

Thank you very much for your response. I cannot understand why the intersection  $\bigcap_{i\in I} M_{i}$ is defined as $0$ when $I$ is the empty set.

I don’t think the intersection question is well-defined, because the intersection depends on the context where all of your modules are defined. Normally the empty intersection would be the full context/universal set, but there’s not a “universal module” by default. So I think that the answer just depends on context. See here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Empty_Set

Taking intersections of more sets makes the intersection smaller, so taking intersections of fewer sets makes it bigger. For the empty intersection, the result is "the universe".  The empty intersection must be as being taken with respect to a fixed universe. In that case, the empty intersection is that whole universe. Otherwise, the definition of the intersection is ${x ,|, \forall i \in I, x \in M_i}$ is the set of all sets, since the predicate $\forall i \in I, x \in M_i$ is vacuously satisfied for any $x$ at all, and that's not allowed in ZFC set theory.

Instead we have to take ${x \in U ,|, \forall i \in I, x \in M_i} = U$ for some particular $U$ which contains all $M_i$.

@Josh Keneda Thank you so much for your hint.

I take just a bit of issue with the type of formulation "we must define" in this answer. The question is using the language of category theory, so one may assume that the definition of modules used is a special case of the definition of a coproduct (whether explicitly referring to that notion, or just using language that coincides with that of a coproduct definition specialized to the case of modules). Then this already says what the sum of an empty family is, by a condition that only a one-element module can satisfy; one does not in addition need to specify this particular case.

Referring to the edited question, the intersection of an empty set of submodules of $M$ is $M$. This is not special to the nature of the algebraic structures (here, module structures); it's generally true that for a set $X$, the intersection operator (local to subsets of $X$)
$$\bigcap{ }_{X}: PPX \to PX,$$
from the double power set to the single power set of $X$, takes the bottom element $\emptyset$ of $PPX$ to the top element $X$ of $PX$.
The reason is that if $\lbrace A_i: i \in I \rbrace$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, then $\bigcap \lbrace A_i\rbrace$ is uniquely characterized by the property that for all $B \subseteq X$,
$$B \subseteq \bigcap \lbrace A_i: i \in I\rbrace \Leftrightarrow B \subseteq A_i \text{ for all $i$}.$$
In the case where $\lbrace A_i: i \in I\rbrace$ is empty, the right side of this equivalence holds vacuously for all $B \subseteq X$, and so the only candidate for the intersection is $X$ itself.
